# How to automatically save images from colab to gdrive in seperate folders whose name are as same as the labels of the respective images?

Tags: python, image-classification, colab

I have a total of 30k images. They are distributed among 32 classes. I want to save these images from google colab to my drive with folder names as their label name. Can it be possible by python code? Otherwise, it will be a tedious task. Any suggestions will be helpful for me. TIA

For example, I have created this.

[image]

These are my labels.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
for i in range(len(unique_arr)):
  ab = plt.imshow(final[i], interpolation='nearest')
  plt.savefig(f"label{unique_arr[i]}.png")
  plt.show()
```

These are those three images

[image]

And the pictures are saved label{}.png

[image]

Comment: How are the images and the labels connected at the moment?

Comment: @liakoyras Kindly check! I have updated the question

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/115953/8560, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74339742/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have already mounted your google drive. The savefig function can take the path and image name as input argument.

```
    images_dir = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Images'
    plt.savefig(f"{images_dir}/label{unique_arr[i]}.png")
```

In the for loop, you can also have this image directory change for every label, where the label name '/label' adds to the image directory path and you are able to classify each image to a folder according to its label.